# Protractor doesn't wait for Angular in the 1st test case of the second spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I run a conf.js which launches 2 specs. Each of these specs has its own base URL. On the 2nd spec, the first test case fails because the test doesn't wait for Protractor. I get this error:

```
Expected 'Hello {{yourName}}!' to equal 'Hello Robert!'.
```

When I modify the conf.js in order to run only the spec which fails, everything runs alright. Protractor just doesn't wait for Angular in the **1st test case** of the **second spec**.
Note: in my spec, I run this command, and I think it might be the one I need to modify in order to solve this issue:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
});
```

Any idea on how I could fix the problem?
**EDIT:** as suggested, here is my conf:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['../specs/*.js'],
  baseUrl: 'https://angularjs.org',
  framework: 'jasmine'
};
```

1st test spec, which runs ok:

```
var donnees = require('../test-data/jeu-de-donnees-demo.js');
var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

describe("Création d'utilisateur", function() {

beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get("http://localhost:3000");
});

using(donnees.prenoms, function (data, description) {
    it("Type de données : " + description, function () {
        var input_prenom = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='name']"));
        var input_nom = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='username']"));
        var bouton_valider = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Créer')]"));
        var nombre_lignes_avant = 0;
        input_prenom.sendKeys(data.prenom);
        input_nom.sendKeys(data.nom);
        var rows = element.all(by.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'users-list')]/li"));
        rows.count().then(function(count){
            nombre_lignes_avant = count;
            bouton_valider.click();
            var nombre_lignes_apres = nombre_lignes_avant + 1;
            var nouvelle_ligne = element(by.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'users-list')]/li[" + nombre_lignes_apres + "]"));
            expect(nouvelle_ligne.getText()).toEqual(data.prenom + " " + data.nom);
        });
    });
});
});
```

2nd one, in which the first test case fails:

```
var donnees = require('../test-data/jeu-de-donnees-demo.js');
var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');
var SiteAngularPageAccueil = require('../pages/site-angular-page-accueil.js');

describe("Suite de test de la feature qui dit bonjour", function() {

var pageAccueil = new SiteAngularPageAccueil();

beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
});

using(donnees.prenoms, function (data, description) {
    it("Chaîne de type " + description, function () {
        testMessageSalutations(data.prenom);
    });
});

function testMessageSalutations(prenomSaisi, prenomVoulu){
    pageAccueil.entrerPrenom(prenomSaisi);
    var prenomAVerifier = (prenomVoulu ? prenomVoulu : prenomSaisi);
    expect(pageAccueil.message_salutations.getText()).toEqual('Hello ' + prenomAVerifier + '!');
}

});
```

The test data file...

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
prenoms: {
    'ASCII': { prenom: 'aaa', nom: "eee" },
    'Caractères spéciaux français': { prenom: 'ààà', nom: "ééé" },
    'Caractères spéciaux arabes': { prenom: 'صباح الخير', nom: 'صباح الخير'},
    'Caractères spéciaux chinois': { prenom: '安', nom: '安' },
    'Script': { prenom: "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hoo la laaa');</script>", nom: "<img src='../' onerror=alert('Lolilolz')/>" }
},
```

}

And finally, the page object used in the 2nd spec:

```
var SiteAngularPageAccueil = function() {
    this.champ_nom = element(by.model('yourName'));
    this.message_salutations = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'well')]//h1"));

    this.entrerPrenom = function(prenom) {
        this.champ_nom.sendKeys(prenom);
    };
};

module.exports = SiteAngularPageAccueil;
```

Comment: Please post both of your specs and your protractor config as well.

Comment: Done. Hopefully it will help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you have to `beforeEach()` functions in the second test case? Also, why the first goes to `http://localhost:3000` while the second to `browser.baseUrl`?

Comment: Whoops, I made a mistake while copy-pasting, that's why there are two `beforeEach` functions. I just deleted the second one, which is useless. There are 2 different URLs because of the needs of my project (we have 2 websites but we want to test both of them in the same test project).

Comment: Quick check - does changing `module.exports = SiteAngularPageAccueil;` to `module.exports = new SiteAngularPageAccueil();` make it work? (of course remove the `new` from inside your spec in this case)

Comment: I got exactly the same error unfortunately.